# Use mutate over multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to to apply mutate over multiple columns.

My dataframe contains 10 columns that are named:

```
Anne
Carol
Jane
Sophanie
Gordon
Donald
Jeffrey
Adam
Sophie
Smith
```

Until now I've done the following to select the columns one by one:

```r
dataframe$Anne
dataframe$Carol
```

And so forth.

Now I want to use a `mutate` function so I can select all these 10 names in a single pipe/command. How do I do that?

Comment: check out https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html to learn how to apply a function across more than one column

Comment: Basically the same as this except it’s mutate not group by

Answer (score 0):

With `across()`

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  Anne = 1:10, 
  Carol = 1:10, 
  Jane = 1:10
) %>%  
  mutate(across(Anne:Jane, ~ .x * 2))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
    Anne Carol  Jane
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     2     2     2
 2     4     4     4
 3     6     6     6
 4     8     8     8
 5    10    10    10
 6    12    12    12
 7    14    14    14
 8    16    16    16
 9    18    18    18
10    20    20    20
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's first create a minimal, reproducible example:

```r
dat <- data.frame(Anne = c(1, 2),
                  Carol = c(3, 4),
                  Jane = c(5, 6))

dat
#>   Anne Carol Jane
#> 1    1     3    5
#> 2    2     4    6

library(dplyr)
```

`across()` lets you apply a `dplyr` function to more than one column. In the simplest case, you can apply it to all columns - `everything()`.

Imagine you want to replace all values with 0:

```r
dat |> mutate(across(everything(), ~ 0))
#>   Anne Carol Jane
#> 1    0     0    0
#> 2    0     0    0
```

Most of the times you want to do something more complex, like applying an `if_else` call to multiple columns:

```r
dat |> mutate(across(everything(), ~ if_else(.x <= 3, "small", "big")))
#>    Anne Carol Jane
#> 1 small small  big
#> 2 small   big  big
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>